# Scrollbar thumb visibility in Android Leanback (android tv) app

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-tv, leanback

I'm working on an Android TV project which is using Leanback lib.

What I'm trying to achieve is make visible the vertical scrollbar which comes inbuilt in VerticalGridView (`androidx.leanback.widget.VerticalGridView`).

```
<androidx.leanback.widget.VerticalGridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/color_green"
    app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb"
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
    style="?attr/rowsVerticalGridStyle" />
```

As it shows, I've tried setting Scrollbar size, drawable, thumb style, and every other possible property to make visible the scrollbar.

Now the tragedy is, when i call `verticalGridView.getVerticalScrollbarWidth();` method to check the width, it returns `0`. it seems that Leanback lib is setting VerticalScrollbarWidth to `0` in some place which I can't find.

I also tried looking in other Leanback apps and no apps show scrollbar thumbs though the view is scrollable.

WHY?? Is there any way I can show my users, the scrollbar on Android TV app?

Comment: Hey @keval-langalia -Were you able to find any solution to this issue? I'm trying to do the same